# Variable argument files in a directory to a c code

Tags: c, batch-processing

Disclaimer: C newbie. Sorry if my question is too silly.
I have a c code that I got from a lab website. This code is in c and has the execution format:

./codeName inputfilename.seq long

Here codeName is the source code. Input file 1 is a protein sequence file and long is an additional argument. I have a list of 3000 sequence files in a directory. I would like to run this codeName program on each file and store its output in a variablename that is unique to each inputfilename. In Matlab I do this by using the dir command and then finding common strings in a filename and passing that as the output. However, I have no idea on how to do this in C. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome onboard! You might need to share some of your `codeName` code.

Comment: I think you did not ask the proper question. First I assume that codeName is not the source code but an executable file, and what I understand is that you need a batch of shell using it. But you should say what shell is available (bash, cmd, etc.), and show what you have tried first.

Comment: You could use a `bash` script on Linux or a `bat` file on Windows to execute the `./CodeName` multiple times maybe ?

Comment: This is a job for a shell, e.g. on a *bourne* shell (\*nix systems), do `for seq in *.seq; do ./codeName $seq long >$seq.output; done` ...

Comment: Thanks everyone! @FelixPalmen and Darkpingouin thanks for your tip. I ran it using bash and it runs perfectly. I just finished going through the entire proteome of 10 different species using this approach; that is close to a 100k protein sequence files! Basically, I wrote a script in bash as per your recommendation and could run the c code on entire folders.